# Robot Framework - How to if statement if keyword fails

Tags: robotframework

```
${Var_Name}=  page should contain element  ${ID}
run keyword if  "some keyword"  ${Var_Name}  false
```

If the page doesn't contain the element the test fails, is it possible to ignore the fail and run "some keyword" as it returns false?

Comment: Have you looked through the documentation for the [BuiltIn library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html) to see all of the available keywords?

Answer (score 0):

The keyword 'page should contain element' does not return anything, so ${Var_Name} will not contain a value apart from 'None' when the 'page should contain element' test succeeds.

You could use the keyword "Get Matching Xpath Count" from the selenium2Library and perform the required action in an if/else statement based on the value of the xpath count.

like so:

```
${value}= | Get Matching Xpath Count | [xpath]
Run Keyword If | ${value} > 0 | [keyword]
... | ELSE | [keyword]
```